# Is it possible to have negative beta terms in the Nelson-Siegel model?

Tags: interest-rates, actuarial-science

The Nelson-Siegel model as described in [this paper](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7E/rolf/teaching/NelsonSiegel.pdf) has the following form:
$$ y_t(\tau) = \beta_0 + \frac{(\beta_1+\beta_2)(1- e^{(-m/\tau)})}{\frac{m}{\tau}} - \beta_2e^{(-m/\tau)}
$$

Can the $\beta_s$ here be negative? Under what assumptions are they strictly positive? I couldn't find any assumption of the sort in the referred paper.

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html, which provides the parameters for US Treasury curves estimated by Fed researchers.

Comment: @Helin thank you. I see that although the  are negative, the yield never become negative. Is there some meaning to this? Or am I just reading too much unnecessarily?

Comment: TBH I wouldn't worry about them too much. These parameters aren't even stable from day to day and the jumps don't always mean your results aren't valid.